# Struts html:select dropdown population error saying attribute property is mandatory

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Im using struts 1.1 in a application where i need to populate a drop down from database values and i am set it to the form bean from in my action which display the below jsp.

```
<td width="80%" class="formfield" valign='top'>
    <html:select property="selectedUsedByUserName">
    <html:option value="" >-</html:option>
    <html:optionsCollection property="usedByUserList" label="name" value="staffNo"/>
    </html:select>
</td>
```

And in the form bean i have use below getters and setters,

```
private UserDTO selectedUsedByUser = null;
private HashMap usedByUserListMap = new HashMap();

public UserDTO[] getUsedByUserList() {
    return (UserDTO[]) usedByUserListMap.values().toArray(new UserDTO[0]);
}

public void setUsedByUserList(UserDTO[] usedByUserList) {
    usedByUserListMap.clear();
    if (usedByUserList != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < usedByUserList.length; i++) {
            usedByUserListMap.put(
                    String.valueOf(usedByUserList[i].getStaffNo()),
                    usedByUserList[i]);
        }
    }
}

public String getSelectedUsedByUserName() {
    String selectedUsedByUserName = null;
    UserDTO tempSelectedUsedByUser = getSelectedUsedByUser();
    if (tempSelectedUsedByUser != null) {
        selectedUsedByUserName = String.valueOf(tempSelectedUsedByUser
                .getStaffNo());
    }
    return selectedUsedByUserName;
}

public void setSelectedUsedByUserName(String string) {
    UserDTO tempSelectedUsedByUserName = null;
    if (string != null) {
        tempSelectedUsedByUserName = (UserDTO) usedByUserListMap
                .get(string);
    }
    setSelectedUsedByUser(tempSelectedUsedByUserName);
}

public UserDTO getSelectedUsedByUser() {
    return selectedUsedByUser;
}

public void setSelectedUsedByUser(UserDTO usedByUser) {
    this.selectedUsedByUser = usedByUser;
}
```

But when i print the stack trace of the exception, i see below. What is the reason for this exception please,

> According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute property is mandatory
>   for tag select at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:78)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:373)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:201)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:833)
>   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1501) at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2291) at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2341) at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:870)
>   at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1501) at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2291) at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2341) at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2347) at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:498) at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2291) at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1853) at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:210) at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:435) at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService

I have already set the attribute property in the jsp select tag. Do we need to set it to a value before the jsp loads. I belive we use it to track the option selected after the drop down in populate right? So once we select a value struts will set the selected value right?

Comment: Are you sure that (a) the JSP is actually deployed, and (b) you're looking at the right JSP?

Comment: yes. why you say that pls

Comment: ... Because you *have* a `property` attribute, and I find it very unlikely your app container has a bug in its JSP parser.

Comment: Do i need to initialize the property?

Comment: the air is stating the tag itself does not have a property attribute. It does not matter what the property value is, this is a parsing problem.